# WooCommerce redirect to Reports after login

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to know if theres a function that can redirect all users to WooCommerce Reports page after logging in, instead of showing dashboard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this following code in `functions.php` of your active theme

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    //is there a user to check?
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //check for admins
        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
            // redirect them to the default place
            return home_url()."/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-reports";
        } else {
            return home_url();
        }
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Tested it and works perfectly. Had to customize a little for my needs but thank you sir!